# Perfect Ranking with ties using PHP alone

Tags: php, arrays, ranking, rank

In my attempt to find the perfect ranking solution with ties, I was stuck at giving the correct ranking. Codes will explain what I am trying to achieve better:

I have the following array:

```
$standings = array(
    'player_1' => 30,
    'player_2' => 26,
    'player_3' => 28,
    'player_9' => 28
);
```

Now in order to rank it with ties, I have the following function:

```
function setRanking($standings) {
    $rankings = array();
    arsort($standings);
    $rank = 1;
    $tie_rank = 0;
    $prev_score = -1;
    foreach ($standings as $name => $score) {
        if ($score != $prev_score) {  //this score is not a tie
            $count = 0;
            $prev_score = $score; 
            $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $rank);
        } else { //this score is a tie
            $prev_score = $score;
            if ($count++ == 0) {
                $tie_rank = $rank - 1;
            }
            $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $tie_rank);
        }
        $rank++;
    }
    return $rankings;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(setRanking($standings));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [player_1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 30
            [rank] => 1
        )

    [player_3] => Array
        (
            [score] => 28
            [rank] => 2
        )

    [player_9] => Array
        (
            [score] => 28
            [rank] => 2
        )

    [player_2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 26
            [rank] => 4
        )

)
```

Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [player_1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 30
            [rank] => 1
        )

    [player_3] => Array
        (
            [score] => 28
            [rank] => 2
        )

    [player_9] => Array
        (
            [score] => 28
            [rank] => 2
        )

    [player_2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 26
            [rank] => 3
        )

)
```

The problem is it prints the ranking as `1,2,2,4` whereas it should print `1,2,2,3` according to my assumption. So how can it print 1,2,2,3? Where could thing possibly go wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just change your else block..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your else block, You are not decrements your `$rank` value so its hold the same value as it is. You just do the `$rank - 1` cause its just less 1 to store in a variable not change the main value.

```
foreach ($standings as $name => $score) {
    if ($score != $prev_score) {  //this score is not a tie
        $count = 0;
        $prev_score = $score; 
        $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $rank);
    } else { //this score is a tie
        $prev_score = $score;
        $rank--; // Decrements here
        if ($count++ == 0) {
            $tie_rank = $rank;
        }
        $rankings[$name] = array('score' => $score, 'rank' => $tie_rank);
    }
    $rank++;
}
return $rankings;
```

Comment: Its Okey, Don't forgot to accept this as helpful answer.